# How to animate bar plot with different colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a bar plot with different colors and it works fine. However when I try to make an animation out of it, it behaves strangely. For instance, If I keep resizing the window, I can see the changes on the animation but if I do not resize the animation window, it will not update and refresh. I checked the values & colors for each iteration and they all are correct. Would you kindly help me out understand the issue ?I am sorry if it seems like a superficial question,

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import statistics as st
  import matplotlib.animation as animation

  color=['firebrick','firebrick','firebrick','firebrick']
  a=[1400,1420,1440,1460]
  b=[1000,5000,10000,5000]
  y=1000
  for i in [0,1,2,3]:
       if y<b[i]:
            color[i]='firebrick'
       if y>b[i]:
            color[i]='Blue'

  def update(curr):
       a=[1400,1420,1440,1460]
       b=[1000,5000,10000,5000]
       global color,y
       # check if animation is at the last frame
       if y > 10000: 
             a.event_source.stop()
       plt.cla()
       y=y+100
       print(y)
       for i in [0,1,2,3]:
             if y<b[i]:
                  color[i]='firebrick'
             if y>b[i]:
                  color[i]='Blue'
       print(color)
       plt.axis()
       plt.gca().bar(a,b, align='center',color=color, capsize=10)
       plt.gca().hlines(y, xmin=1400,xmax=1460, color='b')   

 fig = plt.figure()   
 %matplotlib qt
 a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to save it as GIF file and it worked fine

```
a.save('Desktop/animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=30)
```